# ViewThatFits always gets the first view from the content in iOS Widget

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

This is how I have it defined in code:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5) {
        Spacer()
        MonthView() //the first component from the images
        if !entry.services.isEmpty {
            Spacer()
        }
        ViewThatFits(in: .vertical) {
            //VStack {
            //    ForEach(entry.services.prefix(1)) { service in
            //        viewForService(service)
            //    }
            //}
            VStack {
                ForEach(entry.services.prefix(2)) { service in
                    viewForService(service)
                }
            }
            VStack {
                ForEach(entry.services.prefix(3)) { service in
                    viewForService(service)
                }
            }
            VStack {
                ForEach(entry.services.prefix(4)) { service in
                    viewForService(service)
                }
            }
            VStack {
                ForEach(entry.services.prefix(5)) { service in
                    viewForService(service)
                }
            }
        }
        Spacer()
    }
}

func viewForService(_ service: Service) -> some View {
    VStack { ... }
}
```

And this is the effect:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

It always gets **the first** view from `ViewThatFits`. Why? The following screenshots was made one by one by commenting out another `VStack`'s views inside `ViewThatFits`. Above example code with first element commented out was used for the second screenshot.

Either I do not understand how it works or I have missed something important. Because it should work like I expected. In this case it should take the last one with `prefix(5)` and display it.

PS Adding or removing `Spacer` Views doesn't change anything. It still behaves the same way. The eonly difference is that view is not centered then but displayed from the top.

Comment: [Per my Meta advice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/423352/472495), please take care with your spelling. Questions are intended to be kept here permanently, and where they contain errors, a volunteer will generally need to make improvements. We don't have enough people willing to undertake that labour, so not creating the work in the first place is ideal.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewthatfits):

> you provide views in order of preference. Usually this order is largest to smallest, ...

So all what need to be done, is to reverse the order. `.prefix(5)` (the largest) at the top and `.prefix(1)` (the smallest one) at the bottom.

Worked